# Are there any examples of pruning Neural Networks in Mathematica?

Tags: neural-networks

Are there any examples of Pruning in Neural Networks in Mathematica?
Any links or insight would be appreciated.

Thank You
Michel

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much about neural networks, so this probably isn't what you want, but there was a [Wolfram blog](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/05/02/neural-networks-an-introduction/) post that had a little bit of info on "neural network surgery". Hopefully someone can find something more relevant for you! [This link](https://blog.wolfram.com/2018/06/14/launching-the-wolfram-neural-net-repository/) and [this link](https://blog.wolfram.com/2018/05/24/learning-to-listen-neural-networks-application-for-recognizing-speech/) have some more info on NNs.

Comment: Mathematica uses MXNet under the hood for neural networks. If I recall correctly, support for pruning is quite early in MXNet, so we may not see if for some time in Mathematica.